# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' error when pulling data from API with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I know theres quite a few of these open but I can't find any that fix my problem, I'm making a Fortnite Statistics Bot with Python for Discord.

I have the main functionality working (!stats  ) But I'm currently trying to add functionality for the argument "lastgame" you can add to the end of the command to see all the stats for the player's last played game.

The reason the main functionality works is because from the API those show as all seperate things and with quotes around value:

```
7: {key: "Matches Played", value: "83"}
key: "Matches Played"
value: "83"
8: {key: "Wins", value: "0"}
key: "Wins"
value: "0"
9: {key: "Win%", value: "0%"}
key: "Win%"
value: "0%"
10: {key: "Kills", value: "36"}
key: "Kills"
value: "36"
11: {key: "K/d", value: "0.43"}
key: "K/d"
value: "0.43"
```

As you can see they are all seperate and have quotes around the response, however the recentMatches are all in 1 dropdown most without quotes, if I try to pull anything with quotes (like accountId) it works and responds working with that, but it I select something like kills without quotes it gives me the error in the title.

```
accountId: "f487380b-750c-4762-a6a6-6fe129895ae2"
dateCollected: "2018-10-20T17:26:40.74"
id: 887912262
kills: 0
matches: 4
minutesPlayed: 4
platform: 3
playlist: "p10"
score: 246
top1: 0
top3: 0
top5: 0
top6: 0
top10: 0
top12: 0
top25: 0
```

heres my code:

```
if platform not in ('pc','xbl','psn'):
  await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Usage: ' + COMMAND_PREFIX + 'stats <pc,xbl,psn> <name> lastgame')
  return
else:
  lastgame = fortnite_tracker_api_last(platform,words[2])

  if lastgame:
    laststats = lastgame[0]['accountId']
```

and I add that to the discord embed

```
embed.add_field(name="Last Stats", value=laststats + '\n', inline=False)
```

and if I try that with accountId it works and outputs that as the value. however if I change 'accountId' to something like 'kills' I get the error. I need to have all of these show either with multiple values and embed fields or just 1.

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: You can't add an integer and a string together in python. You have to cast the string to an integer (so you can do integer math) or cast the integer to a string (so you can do string concatenation). Try `value=str(laststats) + "\n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error says, `laststats` is an `int`eger, and you can not add an `int` and `str`ing together, for example:

```
>>> 3 + 'foo'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

You can however convert the `int` to a `str`ing, for example by formatting:

```
embed.add_field(name="Last Stats", value='{}\n'.format(laststats), inline=False)
```

or by using the `str(..)` constructor:

```
embed.add_field(name="Last Stats", value=str(laststats) + '\n', inline=False)
```

but the above is probably more elegant, if you want to perform more complicated formatting.

Comment: Thanks this fixed it! <3